# SQL QUERY ON 2 TABLES WITH EXCLUSION

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I'm looking for a sql query to select IDs from the "product" table for "user" 1 that don't appear in the "Fake" table in the "product_id" field for "customer _id" 20 (for example). I hope to be clear enough in my request. Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: could you give us a short summary of what you tried so far?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: I don't see anthing SQL-related here, just an Excel spreadsheet. Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Look up the use of `NOT EXISTS` it's like an "IN" statement in a where clause but allows you to correlate the two queries together so your outer query is the products you want MINUS those that exist in your sub query (the fake ones)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks XQbert. I think I succeeded thanks to your advice. Thank you

```
SELECT P.*, U.name
FROM product P 
INNER JOIN user U
ON P.user_id = U.id
WHERE U.id= '1'
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT F.*
  FROM fake F
  INNER JOIN customer C
  ON F.customer_id = C.id
  WHERE P.id = F.product_id
  AND C.customer_id = 20)
```

Comment: @slideshowp2: There is no other answer to this question. The OP inferred this answer from a comment.

Comment: @brico Awesome!  Glad you were able to get there!